# What's the meaning of the underlined sentence in page 1 of GTM 102?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

[image]

What's the meaning of the underlined sentence in page 1 of GTM 102?

Comment: Does the terminology "algebra" here mean group,ring and module?

Comment: It's a vector algebra: it's a subspace of the complex vector space of all functions $U\to\Bbb C $ and it's closed under (pointwise) multiplication and contains the constant $1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me start with the explicit definition of $\mathcal D(U)$, i.e.
$$
\mathcal D(U) = \{ f: U \to \mathbb C \mid f \text{~is smooth} \}.
$$

Now, an [algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_over_a_field) over the field $k=\mathbb C$ is a vector space with an bilinear from
$$
\cdot: \mathcal D(U) \times \mathcal D(U) \to \mathcal D(U): (f,g) \mapsto f \cdot g.
$$
This bilinear form assigns a ring structure to $\mathcal D(U)$ and is also a multiplication in this sense, but it is not the same as the scalar multiplication!

In our case, this map is defined pointwise. For $f,g \in \mathcal D(U)$, we define $f \cdot g \in \mathcal D(U)$ by 
$$
f \cdot g : U \to \mathbb C: x \mapsto (f\cdot g)(x) := f(x) \cdot g(x),
$$
where the last addition is the addition of complex numbers.
In addition, this map has to satisfy the axioms of a bilinear map, e.g. stuff like linearity with respect to scalars of the field $\lambda (f\cdot g) = (\lambda f) \cdot g$, for $\lambda \in k = \mathbb C$ and the other axioms.

Since the functions of the differentiable structure are complex valued, these properties are satisfied.

The last statement $1 \in \mathcal D(U)$ asserts, that the constant function
$1: U \to \mathbb C: x \mapsto 1$ is an element of the algebra $\mathcal D(U)$.
It is also the unity element with respect to the ring multiplication $\cdot$.

---

If you know a bit of algebraic geometry, you can see that the axioms in the book
point a little bit in the direction of [sheafs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheaf_(mathematics)#Sheaves_on_manifolds).

Hence, topological objects like open set $U, V$ are assigned to rings $\mathcal D(U)$ and $\mathcal D(V)$, an we if $\mathcal U \subseteq \mathcal V$, then we can find a (restriction) morphism $\vert_U: \mathcal D(V) \to \mathcal D(U)$, which is in this case just the restriction of the functions onto the smaller domain.
(See the wikipedia article for the [complete definitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheaf_(mathematics)#Formal_definitions) of sheafs.)

Hence, these a sheaf is a link between topology and algebraic strucutres. 
And they allow to relate purely local with global data, therefore it is no surprise, that they are also important for manifolds. 
(But I am not an expert about that! Don't trust me.)

---

*Details about the vector space structure:*

The addition 
$$
+ : \mathcal D(U) \times \mathcal D(U) \to \mathcal D(U): (f,g) \mapsto f+g
$$
is also defined pointwise by $(f+g) (x) = f(x) + g(x) \in \mathbb C$.

And the scalar multiplication 
$$\mathbb C \times \mathcal D(U) \to \mathcal D(U): (\lambda,f) \mapsto \lambda f,
$$
is defined via $(\lambda f)(x) = \lambda \cdot f(x) \in \mathbb C$.

Comment: So $M$ is assumed to be smooth, isn't it?

Comment: Good point! I guess that you can only talk about $C^{\infty}$ structures on smooth manifolds. (Since if $M$ is only a $C^k$ manifold, then there is no practical definition for $C^\infty$ maps, since the charts may change the differentiability of the chart repesentation of a map. (i.e. for some charts it maybe is smooth, but for others it is only $C^k$, since the chart is only $C^k$)).

But you could also talk about $C^k$ differentiable structures. (In fact, these structures can be used to define manifolds!)